# Installing 14.04 Server to exisiting btrfs subvolume

Tags: server, 14.04, system-installation, btrfs

I have an existing btrfs raid1 volume consisting of 4 disks. This already contains a few subvolumes of which I'm looking to install Ubuntu to one of. I've done the following:

```
mount -o subvolid=0 /dev/sda1 /btrfsroot
btrfs subvol create rootsfs /btrfsroot
btrfs subvol set-default 376 /btrfsroot
mount /dev/sda1 /rootfs   (to ensure I've set the correct id)
```

The installer crashes out after the partitioner though (saying it can't remove needed files from `/target/`). I've set it to use partition `/dev/sda1` as `btrfs` on `/` without formatting.

I've done a fair bit of research but at first glance it's hard to tell what the best practice is with regards installing Ubuntu into an existing `btrfs` subvolume. I've also tried:

- Not partitioning `/dev/sd[a-d]` at all and adding those to the `btrfs` volume. When I install in this manner it kind of works (I have to manually mount `/dev/sda` to `/target/`) but then I get stuck at a `grub` debug shell on reboot
- Partitioning off 100 meg off (as `/dev/sda1`) each disk and creating an `mdadm` array to use as `/boot/` (with `btrfs` partitions as `/dev/s[a-d]2`). Again the installer crashes after partitioning saying it could not delete needed files from `/target/` though nothing is there.

I've read the info [on an Ubuntu wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs) and I'm guessing I'm running into the problems they mention there about set-default breaking Ubuntu's layout. Though my interpretation was that that is only an issue after install - I can't even get that far.

What is the best practice here? My reason for wanting to install onto a separate subvolume is to keep my Ubuntu install distinct from everything else on the drives. Is it safe to do an install into the root-subvolume without risking nuking my data?

Comment: if you want to install Ubuntu on existing btrfs partition, just make sure, that there are no `@` and `@home` subvolumes on it. Those volumes will be created by installer automatically, and you can change their name later (remember to update grub and /etc/fstab !). I've never installed ubuntu on btrfs RAID though.

Comment: I'll give that a go - will it work if I use the whole root of the drive, or do I need a separate ext[34] /boot/ partition?

Comment: I've never tested it *without* separate /boot partition.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Please write that into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### disclaimer

*I've never used btrfs RAID. The solution is tested only on single-volume btrfs root partitions*

---

1. Make sure, there are no `/@` and `/@home` subvolumes on the candidate for root.
2. Launch the Ubuntu installer, and choose *something else* when it asks you about disk partitioning.
3. Mark your btrfs partition as root filesystem, but **don't let the installer reformat it**.
4. Arrange all the other partitions as you like. I always choose to use external `/boot` partition on `gpt` systems, so I can later migrate into something more advanced (e.g. `bcache`) or whatever. (On `gpt` you can have as many partitions as you want, so I see no real drawback of using dedicated `/boot`.)
5. Finish the installation.

The installer will make the `@` and `@home` subvolumes for you. Later you can rename them into something different - just be sure you also update the new name on both `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 16, Mint 15, Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: I tried this in a test VM and it worked ok with RAID-1. I'm now in the process of doing it for real, but the btrfs-convert on my 5.6tb array is taking its time. 4 days so far!

Comment: Editing grub.cfg is not recommended. It contains this warning: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub. I presume because next kernel update, for example, will overwrite these changes. Is there a better way to rename a subvolume?

Comment: @philcolbourn I know it. But empirical evidence tells, that the part of `grub.cfg` that invokes the kernel and instructs it about the name of the root btrfs subvolume **magically survives** `update-initramfs`.

Comment: @Adam, yes I found that out too - hence my edit.